# Google Analytics - Geography

Tags: google-analytics

I have a question on how google analytics geography works particularly for travelling users. For example, if I am a user who is in the city of Sunnyvale and I open an app, Google analytics at a User id level will say number of Users = 1 and location of User = Sunnyvale. I then drive to San Francisco and open the same app. Google Analytics will say , Users =1 (since this is at a user id level) and will say San Francisco = 1.

The question is what happened to the Sunnyvale count? Does that remain as 1 ? Does it change to 0? Is there double counting that takes place?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It remains 1. In GA оne user can have different locations.

See a real example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, quick follow up questions. If the same user goes back to Moscow from Vladimir they wont be counted again in the User's count in the report right , since its at a User id level? 
Is there anyway to check the unique users per city?
Also, how did you manage to get this view that you have shared?

Comment: @Karan If users goes back to Moscow, for Moscow it will be the same user. About report: at first I set up User ID.

Comment: I have user id setup , but how do I pull a report similar to the excel sheet that you have?

Comment: @Karan Create a custom report using User ID and City as dimensions and sessions and user as metrics.

Comment: I forgot to clarify: for using User ID in reports it needs to be set as custom dimension.

Comment: @Karan, you are satisfied with my answer? Why do you not accept it?

Comment: thank you so much , I am new to stack overflow to accept do I need to click on the tick mark ? I just did that.